# Adding JS objects to an array using a cursor loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexeddb

I'm trying to recreate a mySQL/PHP project of mine (a "new tab" style page storing bookmarks with accent colours, folders, and a speed dial / pinned section) in IndexedDB for a client-side storage solution (with hopes of moving it to a Chrome extension).

I like to think I have an OK understanding of JS, however I can't work out why the following is only returning an empty array. From what I can see the "response" array is declared at the begining of the function and should therefore be accessible by the subordinate functions therein. Sticking in console logs does indicate that the array is successfully being pushed to with the objects created by the cursor iterations, however once the cursor finishes, response is left empty.

```
// Specify index and key value OR omit for all
function getItems(ind,key) {
var response = [];
var transaction = db.transaction(["items"],"readonly");
var store = transaction.objectStore("items");

// If args are omitted - grab all items
if(!ind | !key) {
    var cursor = store.openCursor();
    cursor.onsuccess = function(e) {
        var res = e.target.result;
        if(res) {
            var r = {
                "name": res.value['name'],
                "url": res.value['url'],
                "folder": res.value['folder'],
                "colour": res.value['colour'],
                "dial": res.value['dial'],
                "order": res.value['order']
            };
            response.push(r);
            res.continue();
        }
        return response;
    }
} else {
    // If both args are specified query specified index
    store = store.index(ind);
    var range = IDBKeyRange.bound(key, key);
    store.openCursor(range).onsuccess = function(e) {
        var res = e.target.result;
        if(res) {
            var r = {
                "name": res.value['name'],
                "url": res.value['url'],
                "folder": res.value['folder'],
                "colour": res.value['colour'],
                "dial": res.value['dial'],
                "order": res.value['order']
            };
            response.push(r);
            res.continue();
        }
        return response;
    }
}
}
```

Am I being stupid and missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write:

```
cursor.onsuccess = function(e) {
    ...
    return response;
}
```

You're returning a value from that anonymous event handler (which will be ignored). By the time this handler executes, the call to `getItems()` itself has long since completed. You can't simply `return` a value produced by an asynchronous operation like the cursor iteration.

Try this instead:

```
function getItems(callback, ind, key) {
  var response = [];
  var transaction = db.transaction(["items"],"readonly");
  var store = transaction.objectStore("items");
  transaction.oncomplete = function() { callback(response); };

  ...
}
```

And call it as:

```
getItems(function(response) {
  for (var i = 0; i < response.length; ++i) {
    console.log(response[i]);
  }
} /* ind, key */);
```

Comment: Ah I see. I'm still stuck in a synchronous mindset. I hadn't considered that the onsuccess function would be returning to nothing and likely after the function had completed. While I appreciate this method works is there a cleaner way to allow me to query my IndexedDB store that's reusable and variable, ideally outputting to an array of objects?

Comment: Not really @DeanKellham, that is how async code works. Many consider this to be a clean way.

Comment: Future versions of JavaScript will have async support more integrated into the language via async/await keywords, and we're looking to add support to IndexedDB to make it play better with those.